# How to design a CNN (the inputs and outputs of the layers)?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matconvnet

I am a beginner and learning deep learning with baby steps. I have a question about designing the nets. I see in the papers, there are layers with different inputs/outputs and I do not know how to calculate/design before implementation. 
For instance, in this [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf), there are some numbers beside the schematic layers output (see the following figure). How these filter size and other parameters are being specified for a network with a specific image size as input. 
[image]

or in another paper, they have the following design:
[image]

and they have mentioned, For a `256x256` input image,
the total sub-sampling factor of the network is `4`, resulting in
a `64x64xL array`, where L is the number of class labels. How this `64x64` size is being obtained?

How can I learn to design the net and calculates inputs/outputs of layers?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

1. If you pool twice with `stride=2` means you reduce by a factor 2 the image size twice, resulting with a total of x4 reduction (sub sampling) of image size. Hence, if you start with an image of size 256: 256/4=64.
2. How do choose kernel size, number of output of each layer, strides and other design parameters? There's actually no single answer for that and basically many papers/works approach the same tasks with different settings. AFAIK there's no clear guidelines or obvious choice of parameters that suits any specific task.
   That being said, you can find [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00847) surveying some emerging deep nets design patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much Shai, May I ask how the filters are calculated in column #3 of the table, as you can see 64,128, 256,512,512,1024,39 ? Thanks

Comment: @S.EB you might as well chose other numbers.

Comment: Dear Sai, Thank you so much. I read that paper. Really happy to get good information. Thanks for sharing.